# PHP a simple array sort

Tags: php, arrays, arraylist

I got 3 arrays in PHP 
1. Place name - $places
2. Days spent in each place - $days
3. Hours spent in each place - $hours

For eg

```
$places=array(15,12,10,2,78,32);
$days=array(1,0,5,4,3,8);
$hours=array(0,12,8,9,0,14);
```

For places I am keeping places id

My actual worry is I need to sort places array according to alphabetic order of place name ( which is from database )

like

```
$ids=implode(',',$places);
$res=mysql_query("select * from places where WHERE id IN ($ids) ORDER BY name ASC");



while($row=mysql_fetch_array($res)){



echo $row['name']. 'Days Spent ' . $days . 'Hours : '.$hours ; 

}
```

My doubt is simple , I have to show days & hours spent in each places in this MySQL result , ie after sorted/ order by MySQL query ..

Please help ,
Thank you for your time

Comment: Have you considered using objects?

Comment: objects ? actually I didnt understand .. Can you please explain ..

Comment: You should consider it: http://php.net/manual/language.oop5.php

Comment: Bind all of the data on a specific event into an Event object, and have an array of those objects. It makes more sense (logically) to have them together.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your loop:

```
$key = array_search($row['id'], $places);
echo $days[$key];
echo $hours[$key];
```